# What are the equivalents of Swifts integer "Overflow Operators" &*, &+ and &- in Java?

Tags: java, integer, overflow, unsigned, truncation

Swift offers so called "Overflow Operators" &*, *+, &- for integer arithmetics ([Swift Advanced Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)). They are designed to truncate the number of available bits when performing an operation that would lead to an overflow. For example:

```
var unsignedOverflow = UInt8.max // --> 255
unsignedOverflow = unsignedOverflow &+ 1 // --> 0, instead of overflow
```

Since Java doesn't support unsigned integers, there is probably not a real equivalent. In Java 8, there are functions like `Integer.toUnsignedLong(int)` or `Integer.divideUnsigned(...)` ([Java 8 Class Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#divideUnsigned-int-int-)) but unfortunately I cannot use this version of Java.

Is there some (easy) way to mimic the above behavior?

Edit: What I am trying to achieve is multiply and add positive integer values in Java so that the result is always a positive integer value. I tried using the % operator, but it returns the remainder, which can be a negative number.

Comment: All of Java's integer arithmetic operators operate like these Swift advanced operators. They overflow silently and with well-defined behavior.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yes. But there is no data type in Java in which the value 255 with one added to it equals zero. (Although you could emulate it in `byte` if you treat it as unsigned even though it isn't)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Exactly, that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have unsigned numbers. However, you may achieve a similar result by discarding the bits you do not want:

Use `int` or `long`, whichever is sufficient enough for your range. 
Then, for each operation, clear the bits above the range:

```
int abc = 255;
abc += 10;
abc &= 0xFF; // clears any bits other then least significant 8. 
System.out.println(abc); // --> 9
```