# Integer overflow test operator? (&+)

Tags: c, integer, integer-overflow

This question could just be [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) of interpreting the operator incorrectly. But a while ago, I saw someone tweeting about an operator that allegedly can be used to check for integer overflow in C. Namely the `&+` (ampersand-plus) operator, and it could be used simply like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t x, y;

    x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    y = 1;

    if (x &+ y) {
        printf("Integer overflow!\n");
    } else {
        printf("No overflow\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It does seem to work as one would expect, and GCC 6 doesn't throw me any warnings or errors when compiling it with these parameters: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror of.c`

But oddly enough, I have yet to find *any* documentation about this operator, and I never saw it used anywhere. Could someone please explain how this works?

Comment: It [doesn't really test for overflow](https://ideone.com/gcf0Vz), but other than that it's a perfectly good operator (or two).

Comment: Unsigned integers don't overflow, but wrap and signed integers invoke undefined behaviour on overflow. That line does nothing reasonable. Don't even listen to obsure YT videos, blogs or titter posts.

Comment: Totter missives are not suitable source of educatonal material for programming in C.

Comment: I am not sure *what it is* that you've read, but are you sure you didn't read about [**Swift**, which does have `&+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029467/what-are-the-equivalents-of-swifts-integer-overflow-operators-and-in)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I managed to track down the tweet. It was definitely for C. I dunno, I guess I got fooled, then. https://twitter.com/Xeeynamo/status/745690790798712832

Comment: I think you definitely learned a lesson about tatter missives here.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry, but as a non-native English speaker, what the heck are "totter missives" (or "tatter missives" for that matter, as Martin James spelled it)?

Comment: @user966939 - A running gag about Olaf's amusing typo (titter posts).

Comment: Try the `x &*& y` operator and see if it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression

```
x &+ y
```

is parsed as

```
x & (+y)
```

using the unary plus operator, which has no effect (in this case) and just returns y. That means the expression is equivalent to

```
x & y
```

which does *not* test for integer overflow and instead just checks if x and y have any bits in common. Try changing x and y to 1 and see what happens; it'll report an overflow even though none will occur.

Comment: @StoryTeller: hm shouldn't promotion happen anyway whenever the operand is involved in an arithmetic expression?

Comment: @templatetypedef D'oh! I guess I should have tested some more values. The unary plus operator is not one I heard of many times and I didn't see anything obvious when I googled "single plus operator", lol. The name rings a bell though. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @StoryTeller, where do you have this from? In C11 it says that "the usual arithmetic conversions are performed". Integer promotion is part of that process.

Comment: @JensGustedt - [Not normative, I know](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note58), but applicable.

Comment: @StoryTeller, you are reading this wrong. Nsz also says "part of the usual arithmetic conversion". That is a precise technical term from the C standard, for which the C standard precisely prescribes where it applies. Bit operations are included in that.

Comment: @JensGustedt - Yes, it does seem to say so in the description of bitwise AND. Oh well, so no use for unary + after all.

Answer (score 3):

That was probably a joke, there's no such a thing as the `&+` operator. If you write `x&+y`, it is interpreted as `x & (+y)`, where `&` is the binary bitwise and operator, and `+` is the unary plus operator which does nothing besides possibly performing arithmetic promotion (e.g. if `y` is a `short` or `char` it gets promoted to an `int`; in your case it does nothing).

Anyhow, this expression doesn't really have a strict relation with checking for overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably want to use [__builtin_add_overflow](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins) (fully generic, and somewhat less common) or [__builtin_uadd_overflow](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#Integer-Overflow-Builtins) (for `unsigned int`s)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t x, y;

    x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    y = 1;

    if (__builtin_add_overflow(x, y, &x)) {
        printf("Integer overflow!\n");
    } else {
        printf("No overflow\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are no builtin-checking operators in gcc/clang, AFAIK, and `&+` is just `&` followed by a unary `+`.

I'm personally using a wrapper macro that uses these builtins, if they're available, or falls back to a builtin-less solution inspired by the overflow checking code that's available at 
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow